# Postgresql- Select Multiple rows dynamically from a single row

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called month frequency(freq_mnth). If frequency is 3 for a row, the record has to be shown 4 times to complete one year plan with the date counting 3 months + for every record

Likewise of the frequency is 4, the record has to be shown 3 times with the date counting 4 months +

And if frequency is 12, show the record as is

I have a following table

| Id | Date | freq_mnth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 12 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 4 |

I need the following result set

| Id | Date | freq_mnth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-12-01 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 12 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 4 |
| 3 | 2023-06-01 | 4 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 | 4 |

Thanks,
Ramya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite have a solution for you as I don't understand the exact requirements, but you can use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to simply expand a query result to a certain number of rows representing each original row.

```
CREATE TABLE dates
    ("id" int, "mdate" date, "freq_mnth" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO dates
    ("id", "mdate", "freq_mnth")
VALUES
    (1, '2023-01-01', 3),
    (2, '2023-01-01', 12),
    (3, '2023-01-01', 4)
;


select dates.id
, dates.mdate 
 , (dates.mdate + (((generate_series(1,12/freq_mnth)-1)*12/freq_mnth)::text ||' month')::interval)::date as array_value_used_with_time
, generate_series(1,12/freq_mnth) as array_value
from dates
```

Which provides output:

```
id  mdate   array_value_used_with_time  array_value
1   2023-01-01  2023-01-01  1
1   2023-01-01  2023-05-01  2
1   2023-01-01  2023-09-01  3
1   2023-01-01  2024-01-01  4
2   2023-01-01  2023-01-01  1
3   2023-01-01  2023-01-01  1
3   2023-01-01  2023-04-01  2
3   2023-01-01  2023-07-01  3
```

Here's an example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8df7a/13/0)

Comment: The above code using generate_series works like a charm. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!